# How to resize captured image inside imagebox (C# OpenCV winsforms)?

Tags: c#-4.0, opencv, emgucv

I want to resize the captured image inside the imagebox and to set the location of it inside the imagebox. is that possible if yes how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to resize the actual image or only change how it is shown in the ImageBox (for example make the whole image visible if it's too large for the ImageBox right now)?

Answer (score 1):

The imagebox is just a container for the image. If you want to re size you have to transform the image outside the imagebox and then place it back again.